# Viewpager is Not Scrolling when kept with Recylerview

Tags: android

I am using ViewPager and RecyclerView in a FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/regular_view"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

/>
```

I want to hide the ViewPager on Scroll of RecyclerView vertically. It is working.
However the scroll of ViewPager is not working. Why it is happening ?

Comment: isn't FrameLayout  supposed to keep things on top of each other, in that case how would you able to get the ViewPager back, what is happening is RecyclerVIew taking all space covering ViewPager

Comment: what you want is something like DrawerLayout which has othe layout embedded in it :)

Comment: @Pankaj i solved it , but i would like to know how you suggesting with DrawerLayout ?

Comment: i have updated answer, this should give you an overview, there are a lot of ways to do this, it depends on what you want to make :)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for drawer layout used to implement left navigation Drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="sub.fragments.NavigationDrawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer">

</fragment>
```

in this `Linear layout` acts as host for different layout for separate Fragments which can be replaced with `framlayout`

and next Fragment can be anything you want, here's a `fragment` you can have `RecyclerView`

[image]